Multiple errors when compiling FnF
the problem/error I keep on getting
I believe my earlier question wasn't clear enough.
I kept on getting these errors, before these, I had an error called Tea Call, which I went into the game's HSScript.hx, and changed the Tea Call to Tea (blindly followed a github question's response, and it worked). However I kept on getting these errors. Would it be because of the latest version? Any other dependencies? Would it be a version problem with Haxe/Powershell/HaxeFlixel
(Yes, I'm new :o)

Your question is still not clear and might be off-topic. Please read: how to ask. Besides, DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc..
